# yii select2 AJAX error - data.call not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

Select2 ajax call is showing the below error 
When I click in the textfield, Nothing returns and below is the java script error in the firebug console.

```
TypeError: data.call is not a function
(?)() select2.js (line 431)
data = data ? data.call(self, query.term, query.page, query.context) : null;
```

Below is the call from THE VIEW: (yii2 framework)

```
<?= $form->field($model,'country_id')->widget(yii\select2\Select2::className(), [
      'model'=>$model,
      'attribute'=>’country_id',
      // 'language' => 'ru',
      // 'multiple' => true,
      'clientOptions' => [
        // 'allowClear' => true,
        'width' => 300,
        'ajax' => [
          'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('data/country/findcountry') ,
          'dataType' => 'json',
          'data' => 'js:function(term,page) {
                       return {q: term, page: page, page_limit: 10};
                     }',
          'results' => 'js:function(data,page) { return {results: data}; }',
        ],
      ],
]) ?>
```

Please can some one help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Easy but insecure: turn CSRF off `$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;` and try if it works.

Comment: The error was because the Javascript rendered as String . It was solved by putting the javascript function in new yii\web\JsExpression(.....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :
The error was because the Javascript rendered as String . It was solved by putting the javascript function in new yii\web\JsExpression(.....)